# Debugging Rspec Postgres lockups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I am trying to test an app that uses `gem devise_token_auth`, which basically includes a couple extra DB read/writes on almost every request (to verify and update user access tokens).

Everything is working fine, except when testing a controller action that includes several additional db read/writes. In these cases, the terminal locks up and I'm forced to kill the ruby process via activity monitor.

Sometimes I get error messages like this:

```
ruby /Users/evan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec spec/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller_spec.rb(1245,0x7fff792bf310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff15fb73c00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I have no idea how to interpret that. I'm 90% sure the problem is due to this gem and the extra DB activity it causes on each request because I when I revert to my previous, less intensive auth, all the issues go away. I've also gotten things under control by giving postgres some extra time on the offending tests:

```
after :each do
  sleep 2
end
```

This works fine for all cases except one, which requires a timeout before the `expect`, otherwise it throws this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@user1.received_messages.first.read?).to eq true
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UnableToSend: another command is already in progress
       : SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages"  WHERE "messages"."receiver_id" = $1  ORDER BY "messages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

which, to me, points to the DB issue again.

Is there anything else I could be doing to track down/control these errors? Any rspec settings I should look into?

Comment: Have you found any clues since? We are having similar issues with Cucumber.

Comment: Nope, dropped the library that was causing the issues

Comment: Are you sure only one RSpec process is running at a time? Does this issue occur in both feature and model specs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running parallel rspec tasks, that could be triggering this. When we've run into issues like this, we have forced those tests to run in single, non-parallel instance of rspec in our CI using tags.

Try something like this:

```
  context 'when both records get updated in one job', non_parallel do
    it { is_expected.to eq 2 }
  end
```

And then invoke rspec singularly on the non_parallel tag:

```
  rspec --tag non_parallel
```

The bulk of your tests (not tagged with non_parallel) can still be run in parallel in your CI solution (e.g. Jenkins) for performance.

Of course, be careful applying this band-aid. It is always better to identify what is not race-safe in your code, since that race could happen in the real world.